# Gradients in Cartesian and polar.

Tags: polar-coordinates, subgradient

I have the equation of a curve passing through the origin of Cartesian coordinate system as:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x,x>0\\
-x,x<0\\
\end{cases}
$

Note that we assume $f(x)$ is not defined if $x=0$.

How could I show if gradient of $f$ is the same in Cartesian and in polar coordinates.

I know in case $x>0$ we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1$. In case $x<0$ also we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-1$.

Note also that in polar system gradient is taken with respect to $\theta$ and in Cartesian gradient is taken with respect to $x$.

Comment: Is this two dimensions and it should read $f(x, y) = \cdots$? (The right hand side can by the way be written as $|x|$).

Comment: @md2perpe No it is in one dimension. The right hand side is absolute value of x. You right.

Comment: What do you mean with polar coordinates in one dimension, then?

Comment: @md2perpe I did not mean polar in one dimension sorry. Also $f$ is defined in two dimension. In case $x>0$ then $f(x)=x$.

Comment: So it's two dimension with $f(x, y) = |x|$ so that the gradient then is $\nabla f(x, y) = \operatorname{sign}(x) \hat x$?

Answer (score 1):

In case $x>0$ we have:

$f(x)=x$

or,

$y=x$.

Converting to polar system we have:

$\overbrace{r \cos{\theta}}^{x}=\overbrace{r\sin{\theta}}^{y}$.

or,

$\sin{\theta}=\cos{\theta}$

or,

$\tan{\theta}=1$

Here $\tan{\theta}$ is the slop in polar system that is the same with the gradient $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ in Cartesian system while $x>0$. With same approach one could work out the case $x<0$.